# IncompatibleClassChangeError with No Stack Trace

Tags: java, java-native-interface, classloader

I am working on JNI, where the implementation is in java, I am trying to load a class using a custom class loader, I am able to load the class using custom class loader but when I try to invoke a method on the loaded class I get IncompatibleClassChangeError with no stack trace.
Other classes in the project are currently loaded by systemClassLoader, could this error be caused because of that?
Does anyone have some insight on this?

Comment: So i found the cause of this error. I was using customClassLoader to load one of the class while other classes were loaded by the SystemClassLoader, so whenever the method in the class (loaded by customClassLoader) was called it caused the error because it was dependent on the other classes (loaded by SystemClassLoader).